# Opposite of Time.now.advance() in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-advance documents a method `advance()` to add to the current time. Is there an opposite, '`go_back()` method?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think there is but there's nothing to stop you using negative values in `advance`.

```
Time.now.advance(:days => - 1, :hours => -1)
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also try using

```
Time.now.ago(3.days)
Time.now.ago(3.days+3.hours)
```

Comment: for the oppisite direction there is the method `from_now`:
    `2.weeks.from_now # opposite of: 2.weeks.ago`

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following example

```
Time.now - 3.days
```